# Can't make use of proxies in the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, python-requests

I've written a script in python to scrape the requested url made through proxy. I used `shuffle()` within my script to get the proxies randomly. The script is doing fine to some extent. The problem with this script is when it fails to use any valid proxy, It goes for another ***url*** because of the loop. How can I rectify my script in such a way so that it will try to use every proxies (if necessary) in the list to get all the `urls`.

This is my attempt:

```
import requests
from random import shuffle

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page={}&sort=newest"

def get_random_proxies():
    proxies = ['35.199.8.64:80', '50.224.173.189:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128']
    shuffle(proxies)
    return iter(proxies)

for link in [url.format(page) for page in range(1,6)]:
    proxy = next(get_random_proxies())
    try:
        response = requests.get(link,proxies={"http": "http://{}".format(proxy) , "https": "http://{}".format(proxy)})
        print(f'{response.url}\n{proxy}\n')
    except Exception:
        print("something went wrong!!" + "\n")
        proxy = next(get_random_proxies_iter())
```

Output I'm having:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1&sort=newest
35.199.8.64:80

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest
50.224.173.189:8080

something went wrong!!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest
50.224.173.189:8080

something went wrong!!
```

You can see that the two urls `'page=3&sort=newest'` and `'page=5&sort=newest'` did not respond whereas my two proxies are still working.

Postscript: They are free proxies so I published them intentionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
def get_random_proxies():
    proxies = ['35.199.8.64:80', '50.224.173.189:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128']
    shuffle(proxies)
    return proxies

for link in [url.format(page) for page in range(1,6)]:
    for proxy in get_random_proxies():
        try:
            response = requests.get(link,proxies={"http":proxy , "https": proxy})
            print(f'{response.url}\n{proxy}\n')
            break  # success, stop trying proxies
        except Exception:
            print("something went wrong!!" + "\n")
```

I'm not sure what the plan with `return(iter(...))` and `next(result)` was, but a more traditional method would be just to return the list, then loop over some portion of it, as needed.  You've already made the list, returning it takes no extra effort.

Comment: @Topto The second/inner for loop iterates over the return result of `get_random_proxies()` -- so over the shuffled proxy list.  At each iteration, it tries to access a link through a proxy.  This attempt may raise an exception, and if it does, a message is printed and the loop continues.  If *it doesn't raise*, it continues inside the `try` block, first printing a different message and then breaking.  The `break` statement will break to the inner `for` loop, meaning that no more proxies are attempted for this page.  The outer loop remains unaffected, and the rest of the pages will be fetched